# Limit the time people can spend in the review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues

This proposal might sound provocative, and maybe it is: How about limiting the time (or the amount of reviews) spent in the review-queues?

I have found that I myself get less lenient with every question that I review in a row. I might end up voting down a question, just because I am loosing my nerve over the suspicion that once again someone is just trying to outsource his homework-assigement.

On the other hand I have experienced that a question was "vote-closed" while I was in the middle of answering it. The comments later revieled that people were just to irritable after a long days work. They voted down the question not because the question in itself was bad, but because they disliked a comment the original auther made on her own question.

I think that two or three days a week off of the review queue can do you a lot of good. And it reduces the risk of alienating new members of SO, just because some reviewer was too annoyed over another "Syntax-Error-What-Does-It-Mean"-Question (...which is a valid question by the way, a duplicate most probably, but valid indeed...).

Comment: So you want to limit the number of consecutive days one can review before having to "take a break"?

Comment: I have no idea why I would need a break ...

Comment: I propose that we only let users review when they have a medical certificate that they sleep well, aren't stressed and are in a good mood. But seriously: I see why we need a daily limit, but why would we need two or three days off inbetween?

Comment: @BDL We should also have to pass a breathalyzer as we don't want to drink and  review

Comment: Yes, we should limit the _minimum_ time people spend the review queue.  Then maybe we'd actually get through the backlog of 10k items in the close vote queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver: How could I have missed this? :)

Comment: People should not review when tired, drunk or after using any controlled substances, eg. cannabis, cocaine, heroin, PCP or PHP.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well I would never be able to review then.

Answer (score 11):

There are many bad side effects with this proposal.

The time required for each review queue will vary and in the same queue, it will vary for each post.

For example some entries in the CV queue need 2-3 minutes (some need more than that if it is a dupe request. We have to cross check it). But some need only seconds.

Setting a limit and asking the person to complete the review tasks within given period **will encourage robo reviews** which is very very bad for the site.

The other option you proposed is limit the number. It is already there. You can review 40 items per day in each queue except triage. In triage, it will toggle between 20 and 40 according to the size of it(150 is the borderline).